# Is Junketsu conscious?

Tags: kill-la-kill

[Why is Senketsu the only Kamui that can talk?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/10047/7579) is a related, but slightly different question.

Senketsu is the only uniform that can talk, and apparently he can only talk to Ryuuko because their brains are connected at some level by Life Fibers. He also seems to be the only uniform that can move and think on its own.

However, late in the series, when Ragyo forces Ryuuko to put on Junketsu, it seems like Junketsu might have a consciousness—it might be able to think, even if it can't speak or move. It seems to have a will; it resists being removed by Ryuuko, and after she tears it off, Satsuki is only able to wear it because it was infused with some of Ryuuko's blood and Senketsu's Life Fibers, which changed its "personality" in some way. It also seemed like Junketsu might be creating some of the visions in Ryuuko's mind while she wore it, like when she saw herself at a wedding. But the scene was ambiguous; it could have also been Ragyo and Nui creating these visions and making Junketsu bind itself to Ryuuko.

We never see Junketsu talk or move, and it seems safe to assume it can't. But does Junketsu actually have a consciousness, or was it just made to behave this way by Ragyo and Nui?

Comment: I think its consciousness is not as good to be at sentient level as Senketsu's because it wasn't created with that purpose in mind, and all life fiber clothing has animal instincts to cling to wearers to some extent, and it's what we see.

Comment: @Hakase That's an interesting idea that didn't occur to me—that Junketsu might be conscious, but lack the ability to think and just have the instinct to grab on to people, like insects or shellfish do.